Looking for some OAuth project design guidance (React frontend + FastAPI backend)
I am implementing an SPA frontend in React that makes requests to a Python FastAPI backend.
Using client-side Authorization Code flow with PCKE (OAuth2.0), users authenticate their Spotify account and I currently store the access token in LocalStorage in the browser.
I am trying to pass this access token from my frontend to my FastAPI backend to make the more logic-intensive requests to the Spotify API, but the only way I have been able to do so is by providing the token in the URL parameters, which feels wrong.
After doing a lot of research, I see that this general design of client-based auth is vulnerable to XSS attacks and is generally not recommended (same with using LocalStorage, over say HTTP-only cookies). I especially appreciated the explanation provided in this Stackoverflow post.
This is my first full-stack app so I am slightly overwhelmed by all the layers that I am responsible for... I am also new to authentication procedures so I am happy to be learning and putting these skills into practice, but I want to just make sure I wasn't going over the top:
TLDR; Since I have a viable backend in my architecture already, is there any reason for me not to implement server-side authentication, specifically the Backend for Frontend pattern? Or is there an easy and somewhat reasonably secure way to pass the access token from my frontend to my backend, continuing with my current approach?
(I know I will also have to add authentication between my frontend and my backend down the line, after I learn how to deploy the individual resources for each... I hope I haven't bitten off more than I can chew!)
Thank you so much for your thoughts/advice!!

I personally prefer to do server-side authentication because it provides more security and offers a number of implementation options. You can start with this FastAPI tutorial: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/, which will give you a basic understanding of how it can be done on the backend. Additionally, note that the example in that article can be amended with any custom logic you might require.
Also there is a number of python packages which will help you to implement integration with third party apps. For example this one for specifically for spotify https://pypi.org/project/spotify/.
If I were you (and if I understand requirements right) I would create endpoint for oauth which will do:

Authenticate user in spotify and return its data
After the data is returned and parsed it is added to db if user's email/spotify_user_id not exists.
Generate some kind of token and return it front-end

Also you will need an endpoint to get user information. It can recieve a generated token in the header, decode it and return information from db/or not db. You can store any information in the token. You can find a number of articles about auth tokens on the Internet.
Hope it helps!
